# Cassandra Keyspace export from windows single node instance

Tags: cassandra

I tried exporting cassandra keyspace from windows single node instance on CQlshell command with the following command

```
cqlsh> -e 'DESCRIBE keypspace demo' > dump.cql
```

it's not working for me. I am using cassandra version of 3.5.0 and cqlsh version of 5.0.1 and CQL spec 3.4.0. What I am missing here?

PS: I do need to export data along with schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to run the following command from command prompt

Go to CASSANDRA_HOME/bin directory where CASSANDRA_HOME is directory where cassandra is installed.

```
cqlsh -e "DESCRIBE keypspace demo" > "dump.cql"
```

**Note:** Double quotes is required instead of single quotes.

The above command will only export the schema. Use `COPY` command to export the data to csv files and then import it back.
Else you can also use SSTableLoader to load the data using SSTables from data directory